# Dynamic tables with dash mantine components and dropdown

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I would like to create a dynamic table in a Dash App using the dash_mantine_components
(dmc) library and the dmc.Table() component. The update should be based on the value selected through the default dcc.Dropdown() component of Dash.

The dataset I am using is the 30000 Spotify Song dataset available from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/joebeachcapital/30000-spotify-songs).

The output I am searching for is a dynamic table that shows the top 10 artist for a specific genre and subgenre.

I tried to create some callbacks to be used in the layout but nothing really works.

For instance, I tried with this:

```
@app.callback([Output("10_artist_top", "table")], Input("genre-dropdown", "value"), Input("subgenre-dropdown", "value"))
def top_10_artist_presence(genre, subgenre):    df = data.copy()
    sub_df = df[(df['Genre']==genre) & (df['Subgenre']==subgenre)]
    artists = sub_df['Artist'].value_counts().reset_index()[0:10]

    header = [
        html.Thead(
            html.Tr(
                [
                    html.Th('Artist'),
                    html.Th('Number of songs')
                ]
            )
        )
    ]

    row1 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][0]), html.Td(artists['count'][0])])
    row2 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][1]), html.Td(artists['count'][1])])
    row3 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][2]), html.Td(artists['count'][2])])
    row4 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][3]), html.Td(artists['count'][3])])
    row5 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][4]), html.Td(artists['count'][4])])
    row6 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][5]), html.Td(artists['count'][5])])
    row7 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][6]), html.Td(artists['count'][6])])
    row8 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][7]), html.Td(artists['count'][7])])
    row9 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][8]), html.Td(artists['count'][8])])
    row10 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][9]), html.Td(artists['count'][9])])

    body = [html.Tbody([row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10])]
    table = [html.Thead(header), html.Tbody(body)]
    return table
```

And with this:

```
@app.callback(Output("top_10_artists", "table"), Input("genre-dropdown", "value"), Input("subgenre-dropdown", "value"))
def top_10_artist_presence(genre, subgenre):
    df = data.copy()
    sub_df = df[(df['Genre']==genre) & (df['Subgenre']==subgenre)]
    artists = sub_df['Artist'].value_counts().reset_index()[0:10]
    table_data = artists.to_dict('records')
    return table_data
```

But with no luck. At the moment, the code return errors like the following (with the first piece of code), or nothing at all (with the second piece of code).

```
SchemaLengthValidationError: Schema: [<Output `top_10_artists.table`>]
Path: ()
Expected length: 1
Received value of length 2:
    [Thead([Thead(Tr([Th('Artist'), Th('Number of songs')]))]), Tbody([Tbody([Tr([Td('The Chainsmokers'), Td(20)]), Tr([Td('Kygo'), Td(16)]), Tr([Td('Avicii'), Td(15)]), Tr([Td('Martin Garrix'), Td(15)]), Tr([Td('Calvin Harris'), Td(14)]), Tr([Td('David Guetta'), Td(13)]), Tr([Td('Tiësto'), Td(10)]), Tr([Td('Armin van Buuren'), Td(9)]), Tr([Td('Marshmello'), Td(8)]), Tr([Td('Zara Larsson'), Td(8)])])])]
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: If we were to create a new table with id "table_id" from the `table` variable returned by the first callback, we would do `dmc.Table(id="table_id", children=table)`, so you just need to fix the output id and prop for that callback to work properly, that is, `Output("table_id", "children")`. The logic in the second callback could work if you were using a [DataTable](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable) instead of dmc.Table or html.Table.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion @EricLavault. The problem is that if I use the suggested solution I receive back an error like "NameError: name 'table' is not defined"

Comment: @EricLavault I managed to solve the problem by defining the header as the first row of the table body! Now the only problem is the formatting (the table only occupies part of the card where I display it. With a "static" table the whole card space is occupied

Comment: I meant you need to fix the callback output property, ie. `Output("<your_dmc.Table_id>", "children")`, regarding the function itself, `header` and `body` looks ok so you can just `return header + body`.

Comment: Thanks @EricLavault ! Now it is clear and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found thanks to  EricLavault suggestion of removing the square brackets around "Output("top_10_artists", "children")" from my code and by returning header+table as output of the function
The final callback is the following:

```
@app.callback(Output("top_10_artists", "children"), Input("genre-dropdown", "value"), Input("subgenre-dropdown", "value"))
def top_10_artist_presence(genre, subgenre):
    df = data.copy()
    sub_df = df[(df['Genre']==genre) & (df['Subgenre']==subgenre)]
    artists = sub_df['Artist'].value_counts().reset_index()[0:10]

    header = [html.Thead(html.Tr([html.Th('Artist'), html.Th('Number of songs')]))]

    row1 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][0]), html.Td(artists['count'][0])])
    row2 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][1]), html.Td(artists['count'][1])])
    row3 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][2]), html.Td(artists['count'][2])])
    row4 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][3]), html.Td(artists['count'][3])])
    row5 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][4]), html.Td(artists['count'][4])])
    row6 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][5]), html.Td(artists['count'][5])])
    row7 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][6]), html.Td(artists['count'][6])])
    row8 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][7]), html.Td(artists['count'][7])])
    row9 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][8]), html.Td(artists['count'][8])])
    row10 = html.Tr([html.Td(artists['Artist'][9]), html.Td(artists['count'][9])])

    body = [html.Tbody([row1, row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9, row10])]

    return header+body
```

in the app, the receiving code is the following:

```
dmc.Col(dmc.Card(children=[
    dmc.Text("Top 10 artist of the Genre", size='lg', color='dimmed', weight=500, align='center'),
    dmc.Table(id='top_10_artists'),
], withBorder=True, shadow='lg', radius='md'), span='auto'),
```